# Effect of rowspan on cell referencing

Tags: javascript, dom, css-tables

I had always thought that rowspan merely spanned table cells for display purposes only and that the underlying cells continued to remain separate.  Some experimentation has led me to believe otherwise.  Esperientation has shown that the spanned cells are actually consolidated into a single cell.  This plays havoc with cell referencing particularly in a dynamic table where the number of rows and other factors are constantly changing.  It would sure seem nice to me if one could specify that the underlying cells not be consolidated; or, otherwise dealing with the referencing havoc raised by the consolidation.  Is there some graceful way to deal with this?  Thanks.

I tried referencing cells outside the spanned area and found that it doesn't work properly after rowspanning has been introduced.

Comment: What is your qestion1? This is exactly how table should be interpreted.